Asynchronous CPU-Bounded task PYTHON
I have a class "FXvolatility" which can interpolate some value based on two inputs (float, datetime) via this following method:
async def interpolate_volatility_async(self, udl:str, expiry:str, strike:float, price_date: str = None) -> float:
        """Interpolate the volatility for a given currency pair.

        Parameters
        ----------
            udl : str
                The currency pair to get the volatility for.
            expiry : str
                The expiry date for the volatility.  (format: 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            strike : float
                The strike for the volatility.

        Returns
        -------
            float
                The interpolated volatility for the currency pair.
        """
        
        
        if not hasattr(self,'vols') and price_date == None:
            #raise an error if the volatility models have not been built yet and no price date has been provided
            raise ValueError("Volatility models have not been built yet, please provide a price date in the interpolate_volatility method.")
        elif not hasattr(self,'vols') and price_date is not None:
            #build the volatility models if they have not been built yet and a price date has been provided
            self.__build_all_volatility_models(price_date)

        #convert the dates to datetime objects
        expiry = pd.to_datetime(expiry)
        
        #handle the errors for the currency pair
        self.__udl_error_handling(udl)
        #handle the errors for the interpolation of the currency pair
        self.__interpolate_error_handling(udl, self.__price_date, pd.to_datetime(expiry))

        #get the time to maturity
        ttm = (expiry - self.__price_date).days/365
        
        #get the strike volatility for all ttms
        ttms_and_vols = {ttm : self.vols[udl][ttm](strike) for ttm in self.vols[udl]}

        
        #interpolate the volatility with a cubic spline
        cs = CubicSpline(list(ttms_and_vols.keys()), list(ttms_and_vols.values()), bc_type = 'natural')

        #return the interpolated volatility
        return float(cs(ttm))


I declared it as an async def to use it asynchronously. Now I have maybe 500 floats (eg.strikes) and 500 datetimes(eg. maturity).  I tried to test it on Jupyter Notebook with gather taks :
async def build_surface(vol_model, udl, strikes, expiries):
    surface = {{}}
    tasks = []

    for expiry in expiries:
        for strike in strikes:
            
            tasks.append(
                vol_model.interpolate_volatility(udl, strike, expiry)
                )
    
    volatilities = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return volatilities
async def main():
    vol_surface = await build_surface(vol, 'EURUSD', strikes, dates)
    return vol_surface
    

test = await main()

But I don't understand why the execution time of this "asynchronous" function is the same as a synchronous version... Thanks a lot for your help !
I did not tried something else, because I don't know any other manner to do asynchronous coding. I expected a faster execution of this.
EDIT1 :
comment section helped me a lot, @FJSevilla talked about multiprocessing/concurrent.futures. This works so well (from 2min exec time to 40sec), I've done some research about it combined with the comments of the topic. Here's what I've understood :

Asyncio doesn't match with CPU Intensive tasks, as a computer usually have only one CPU, multitasking is impossible. That is why IO tasks works well (IO Tasks meaning HTTP Requests, API, etc...), because these aren't CPU intensive tasks but just communication between "servers".
We can optimize execution time by using parallelization of tasks,
just a division of different and independent tasks in one and unique
CPU.

It it possible that all I've said above isn't correct and this is my interpretation so don't hesitate to correct :)

Let me ask you a different question: why do you expect the execution time to be different? Python is incapable of parallelizing CPU intensive tasks (not in one process anyway). Regardless of whether you use threads, or async, or anything else.

asyncio is intended for IO-bound tasks, it runs on a single thread but offers significant advantages over threading. With threading the same thing happens, but in this case because of the GIL that ends up making that nothing is executed in parallel, maybe this will change in the future PEP-703 but it will be a long way if it finally happens. Currently for CPU-bound tasks you are left with multiprocessing/concurrent.futures (with multiprocessing), or use the C-API and release the GIL there.

Note that your function 's name interpolate_volatility_async yet you are trying to reference a coroutine named interpolate_volatility. Aside from that, all of your tasks run in the same, single thread. Only when one task goes into a wait state (for example, waiting for an I/O operation to complete) can a different task execute. You cannot have two tasks in the same thread using the CPU at the same time.

thanks all for your answers I understand better how async works with python. So, just to be sure I got it, for now, I'm clearly unable to shorten the execution time of this procedure because this is CPU intensive tasks ? As I have one CPU (obviously) I am unable to separate each task concurrently ?

@FJSevilla, So Multiprocessing/concurrent.futures could help me to reach a better execution time for CPU intensive tasks ?

Since thread-based parallelization is not possible in CPython because of the GIL, you are left with process-based parallelization, with multiprocessing or concurrent.futures using multiprocessing you can parallelize the execution of the code and take advantage of each core of your CPU, instead of running everything in a single process/thread (using a single core).

That said, it is not a magic solution, depending on the specific nature of your problem it can be an excellent solution, acceptably good or not really worth it.  MP has its disadvantages, for example, launching processes is much heavier than threads and sharing memory between processes is more complicated and restrictive. You will also have to balance well how many processes to launch, how to distribute the load between the pool of processes and secure communication between them if necessary.

If you are interested I think this article: https://realpython.com/python-parallel-processing/) gives a pretty good general overview of the topic.
